# Why my forEach stops after connecting to my database?

Tags: node.js

The code forEach is here:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'group-counter');
  fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
          return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
      } 
      files.forEach(function (file) {
          shell.exec('node group-counter/'+file+'/index.js')
      });
  });
```

And in every index.js that is in that directry includes code to connect database:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SRV, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to database")
});
```

Why my forEach is stopping after connecting to database at first file?

Comment: I think you need to use `Promise.all` with `files.map` instead of forEach since the code is asynchronous.

Comment: @callback it's still stoping on first file connecting to databse

Comment: Does it work if it's not forEach? Is the problem with doing this multiple times or is it just a problem with the connection to the DB?

Comment: @uyyes Is there more than one file in in `files` then?

Comment: @VLAZ it's problem with forEach as once I put connect to database code, it doesnt loop for other files in this folder.

Comment: @Zimano Yes it has more than one files

Answer (score 0):

This line was the problem. Node js does not have any global variable called shell.

```
shell.exec('node group-counter/'+file+'/index.js')
```

instead, use

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'group-counter');
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    }
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        exec('node group-counter/'+file+'/index.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I have that variable just it cutted while copying and pasting into overflow.